# Selenium radio input return element not interactable

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I am using selenium and python 3.X to login into a bank.

I have a `input type="radio" class="switch-input"` with two options Personal/Business when default is Personal

```
elem1=browser.find_element_by_id('business')
elem2=browser.find_element_by_id('personal')
```

and checking  with

```
elem1.get_attribute('checked') 
elem2.get_attribute('checked')
```

I am getting the expected results (True for the elem2 and None for elem1)

But when using elem2.click() i am getting error :
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I tried to change to find_element_by_xpath and to wait but the same results.

Any ideas?
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="custom-switch">
                            <div class="switch switch-blue">
                                <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" id="personal" value="Personal" checked="checked" />
                                <label for="personal" class="switch-label switch-label-on personal">Personal</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view" id="business" value="Business" />
                                <label for="business" class="switch-label switch-label-off business">Business</label>
                                <span class="switch-selection"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to press on the label

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for=\'business\']').click()
```

Comment: Same for me. Have you ever discovered the reason why this works as such?